# is entity.components returning an array?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am learning A-Frame and JavaScript, and I'm curious about this.

entity.components seems to returns an object that contains all the components attached to an entity, but to access one of the components, you can put the name of the component you want to access in square brackets, like you might do with an array.

for example:  entity.components['geometry']

So I'm assuming that the object being returned by entity.components is actually an array.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an object, which properties correspond to the attached components.

Both:

- components.myComponent (dot notation)
- components["myComponent"] (bracket notation)

are ways to access object properties.

---

If it was an array, you'd have to provide an array index in the brackets. Consider this simple example:

```js
let array = ["one", "two"]
let obj = {
    one: "one",
    two: "two",
}

console.log("array[1]:", array[1])
console.log("array['one']:", array["one"])
console.log("obj[1]:", obj[1])
console.log("obj['one']:", obj["one"])
```